# How to call a custom JSON request, then build a collection of models from that, using Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone.js and have been trying to understand three things:
1) How and where to call a custom JSON request?
2) How to translate that JSON request into a model?
3) How to create a collection of those models?

My JSON looks something like this:

```
{"flavor": "vanilla", 
 "message": "ok", 
 "count": 10,
 "rows": [{"data":["this", "is", "123", "something"],
           "moreData": "more stuff here",
           "moreInfo": "more info here"},
          {"data":["even", "more", "456", "something"],
           "moreData": "even more stuff here",
           "moreInfo": "even more info here"},
          {"data":["it", "doesn't", "123", "end"],
           "moreData": "more and more stuff here",
           "moreInfo": "more and more info here"}]
}
```

I want to have each "data" be an Item. I want a List to contain many Items.

I have to make a custom JSON request (not via $.ajax or anything like that - it is in a separate library that has to be called via a specific function, that provides a callback option) - do I make this call in the Backbone.Model or the Backbone.View?

Basically the JSON response format that I will be getting is not within my control, hence the messy sample above. I'd like to format some of this JSON into nicer attributes as a bonus. I was hoping to do it in the Item model.

How can I translate that request into a model? If I have to modify certain attributes?

How can I create a collection of those models? So far I have

```
    var ItemList = Backbone.Model.extend({

    })

    var ItemLists = Backbone.Collection.extend({

      model: ItemList,

    });

    var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

      el: $("#dashboard"),

      template: _.template($("#item-template")),

      initialize: function(){
        this.render();
      },

      render: function(){
        var item = new Item();
        var content = this.template(item);
        $(this.el).html(content);
      }
    });
```

Please help, any Backbone.js experts. This should be a relatively straightforward question for someone experienced!

Answer (score 2):

```
var ItemList = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
        // response = {"data":["this", "is", "123", "something"],
        // "moreData": "more stuff here",
        // "moreInfo": "more info here"}
        // You can make additional changes here
        return response;
    }
});

var ItemLists = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: ItemList,
  parse: function(response) {
      return response.rows;
  }

});
```

Is this what you were thinking? This takes the `rows` and makes each one into an `ItemList`. You can do other manipulation within the parse, if needed. Then you can set the `url` and use `fetch`.